# What is the meaning of the term "with/without positioning bosses" in connectors ? (for AXK6A2337YG AND AXK6A2347YG)

Tags: connector, position

I need to understand what is the meaning of positioning bosses? Since the model I need is one with positioning bosses, but almost all available on internet are only without positioning bosses, so is there a problem to order the one without positioning bosses?

Comment: When I RTFM (RTFD?) of the exact part number you linked, it answers your question: "Some connectors have tabs embossed on the body to aid
in positioning. When using these connectors, make sure
that the PC board is designed with positioning holes to
match these tabs." However, I can find no mechanical drawing showing where they are located. So either there's some additional document which I can't find, or the datasheet is crap and the part should therefore not be used. I'd contact Panasonic and ask them where they've hidden the drawings in order to prevent people from buying their product.

Answer (score 3):

A positioning boss is a part that sticks out of a connector that acts as a guide for mounting it, usually onto a PCB. Here’s one example where this connector has two positioning bosses.

[image]

Source: https://acesna.wordpress.com/